# Ensure Type A extends Type B that has a field which is the value of another object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to ensure that type A has a field of a generic type but the name of that field is defined by the value of a field from another object.

E.g. the function:

```
interface IndexedContext<K extends string, T> {
  context: T;
  key: K;
}

type TypeB<P, K, T> = {
  // this field should be named after IndexedContext[key]
  P[K] = T;
}

const Consumer =
  <T extends object, K>(context: IndexedContext<K, T>) => <C extends ComponentType<TypeA>, TypeA extends TypeB: C => {
    .....
  };
```

TypeA (props) should have a field which is the value of the field key in IndexedKey? So that when I use this decorator on a react component and pass a ReactContext to it I can make sure that the props have a field which is the same as the key.

```
@Consumer({context: MyContext, key: 'myKey'})
class MyClass extends Component<MyProps> {}


interface MyProps {
  // compiler should fail if this key is missing.
  myKey: // Type of value of MyContext
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to define any extra [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) (such as `TypeB` sould be in your example), you can use `Record` to get a mapped type from a string literal and a field type.

You also need to capture the instance type not the constructor. If you write `{context: MyContext, key: 'myKey'}`, `context` will be the class `MyContext`, and so `T` will be inferred to `typeof MyContext` not `MyContext`. To get the instance type you could type `context` as `new (...a:any[]) => T`.

Putting it all together:

```
interface IndexedContext<K extends string, T> {
    context: Type<T>;
    key: K;
}
type Type<T> = new (...a: any[]) => T

const Consumer =
    <T extends object, K extends string>(context: IndexedContext<K, T>) => <C extends ComponentType<Record<K, T>>>(cls: C) => {

    };

class MyContext { }
@Consumer({ context: MyContext, key: 'myKey' })
class MyClass extends Component<MyProps> { }


interface MyProps {
    // compiler WILL fail if this key is missing.
    myKey: MyContext// Type of value of MyContext
}
```

**Note** `context` will have to be assigned a class for this to work, you will not be able to directly use interfaces or primitives.

Comment: Thanks! That worked pretty nice. I actually did not need the type Type because the React Context already has the 'type' attached I'm looking for. Now it's working perfectly fine!